# Web scraping with Selenium and Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I’m new in Xpath. I’m trying to scrape a stock website to get name and value of each element.
In my python selenium script I’ve locally extracted the main part of the web page in html_content, as follows.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
dirinstall="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\www\mm\\"
chrome_driver = dirinstall+"\\Webdriver\\chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, options=options)
html_content = """
<html class="ng-scope">
<head data-meta-tags="">
    <title> Stock NYSE </title>
    <ui-layout class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <div data-ng-include="" src="layoutCtrl.template" class="ng-scope">
            <app-root class="ng-scope" _nghost-rqp-c0="" ng-version="8.2.14"></app-root>
            <div ng-class="{'demo-mode': $root.session.user.portfolio.account.type === 'Demo' }" class="ng-scope">
                <div ng-view="" ng-class="layoutCtrl.isBannerShown ? 'banner-shown' : ''" class="main-app-view ng-scope" role="main">
                    <et-discovery-markets-results class="ng-scope" _nghost-rqp-c42="" ng-version="8.2.14">
                        <div _ngcontent-rqp-c42="" class="discover main-content no-footer" ui-fun-scroll="{'class': 'minimize', 'classEl': '.user-head-wrapper, .table-discover', 'scrollContainer': '.table-discover', 'setClassAtScroll': 200 }">
                            <div _ngcontent-rqp-c42="" automation-id="discover-market-results-wrapp" class="table-discover markets-table">
                                <et-discovery-markets-results-list _ngcontent-rqp-c42="" automation-id="discover-market-results-sub-view-list" _nghost-rqp-c44="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                                    <div _ngcontent-rqp-c44="" class="market-list list-view" data-etoro-locale-ns="discoverMarketResultsList">
                                        <et-instrument-mobile-row _ngcontent-rqp-c44="" automation-id="discover-market-results-row" _nghost-rqp-c18="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                                            <et-instrument-trading-mobile-row _ngcontent-rqp-c18="" automation-id="watchlist-grid-instruments-list" _nghost-rqp-c47="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                                                <div _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" class="row-wrap">
                                                    <div _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" automation-id="watchlist-item-list-wrapp-instrument" class="instrument-cell name-cell">
                                                        <div _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" class="avatar-img-wrap"> </div>
                                                        <div _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" automation-id="watchlist-item-grid-wrapp-instrument-info" class="avatar-info">
                                                            <div _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" automation-id="watchlist-item-grid-instrument-name" class="symbol">A</div>
                                                            <div _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" automation-id="watchlist-item-grid-instrument-full-name" class="name positive"> 0.68 (0.90%) </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <et-buy-sell-buttons _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" automation-id="watchlist-item-grid-instrument-buy-sell-container" class="instrument-cell buy-sell-buttons" _nghost-rqp-c24="">
                                                        <et-buy-sell-button _ngcontent-rqp-c24="" _nghost-rqp-c27="">
                                                            <div _ngcontent-rqp-c27="" class="prices no-label positive-change" automation-id="buy-sell-button-container-sell">
                                                                <div _ngcontent-rqp-c27="" class="trade-button-title">S</div>
                                                                <div _ngcontent-rqp-c27="" automation-id="buy-sell-button-rate-value" class="price">75.<span class="after-decimal">85</span></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </et-buy-sell-button>
                                                        <div _ngcontent-rqp-c24="" class="space-gap"></div>
                                                        <et-buy-sell-button _ngcontent-rqp-c24="" _nghost-rqp-c27="">
                                                            <div _ngcontent-rqp-c27="" class="prices no-label negative-change" automation-id="buy-sell-button-container-buy">
                                                                <div _ngcontent-rqp-c27="" class="trade-button-title">B</div>
                                                                <div _ngcontent-rqp-c27="" automation-id="buy-sell-button-rate-value" class="price">76.<span class="after-decimal">03</span></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </et-buy-sell-button>
                                                    </et-buy-sell-buttons>
                                                </div>
                                                <et-trade-item-card-action _ngcontent-rqp-c18="" _nghost-rqp-c15="">
                                                </et-trade-item-card-action>
                                            </et-instrument-trading-mobile-row>
                                        </et-instrument-mobile-row>
                                        <et-instrument-mobile-row _ngcontent-rqp-c44="" automation-id="discover-market-results-row" _nghost-rqp-c18="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                                            <et-instrument-trading-mobile-row _ngcontent-rqp-c18="" automation-id="watchlist-grid-instruments-list" _nghost-rqp-c47="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                                                <div _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" class="row-wrap">
                                                    <div _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" automation-id="watchlist-item-list-wrapp-instrument" class="instrument-cell name-cell">
                                                        <div _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" class="avatar-img-wrap"> </div>
                                                        <div _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" automation-id="watchlist-item-grid-wrapp-instrument-info" class="avatar-info">
                                                            <div _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" automation-id="watchlist-item-grid-instrument-name" class="symbol">AA</div>
                                                            <div _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" automation-id="watchlist-item-grid-instrument-full-name" class="name negative"> -0.11 (-1.46%) </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <et-buy-sell-buttons _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" automation-id="watchlist-item-grid-instrument-buy-sell-container" class="instrument-cell buy-sell-buttons" _nghost-rqp-c24="">
                                                        <et-buy-sell-button _ngcontent-rqp-c24="" _nghost-rqp-c27="">
                                                            <div _ngcontent-rqp-c27="" class="prices no-label negative-change" automation-id="buy-sell-button-container-sell">
                                                                <div _ngcontent-rqp-c27="" class="trade-button-title">S</div>
                                                                <div _ngcontent-rqp-c27="" automation-id="buy-sell-button-rate-value" class="price">7.<span class="after-decimal">44</span></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </et-buy-sell-button>
                                                        <div _ngcontent-rqp-c24="" class="space-gap"></div>
                                                        <et-buy-sell-button _ngcontent-rqp-c24="" _nghost-rqp-c27="">
                                                            <div _ngcontent-rqp-c27="" class="prices no-label negative-change" automation-id="buy-sell-button-container-buy">
                                                                <div _ngcontent-rqp-c27="" class="trade-button-title">B</div>
                                                                <div _ngcontent-rqp-c27="" automation-id="buy-sell-button-rate-value" class="price">7.<span class="after-decimal">47</span></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </et-buy-sell-button>
                                                    </et-buy-sell-buttons>
                                                </div>
                                                <et-trade-item-card-action _ngcontent-rqp-c18="" _nghost-rqp-c15="">
                                                </et-trade-item-card-action>
                                            </et-instrument-trading-mobile-row>
                                        </et-instrument-mobile-row>
                                    </div>
                                </et-discovery-markets-results-list>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </et-discovery-markets-results>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ui-layout>
    </body>

</html>
"""

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=html_content))
#results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='ng-star-inserted']")
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[et-instrument-mobile-row and @class='ng-star-inserted']")
print('Number of results', len(results))
```

I don’t know why if I search ‘et-instrument-mobile-row’ I get only 1 element instead of 2, and if I search both ‘et-instrument-mobile-row’ and 'ng-star-inserted' I get 0 elements.
Looking at the example my goal is to get the symbol and current value of buy/sell (price and after-decimal).

Something like:

[A, 75.85, 76.03]

[AA, 7.44, 7.47]

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to the help of @firstbass after stepped on the first element I went in deep to get symbol e different prices for sell/buy as follows:

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have some malformed HTML and Selenium is unsure how to parse it. I noticed this line:

```
 <div _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" class="avatar-img-wrap"><img _ngcontent-rqp-c47="" automation-id="watchlist-item-grid-instrument-avatar" class="avatar-img" src="https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/a/150x150.png" alt="Agilent Technologies Inc">
```

This `<img>` tag is unclosed. You can see that the syntax highlighting also gets confused here too.

<strike>Otherwise, the XPath you are searching by looks generally well formed.</strike>

**Edit:** Looked at it closer. Your attribute name should be where the `*` is.
Here is your XPath:

```
"//et-instrument-mobile-row[@class='ng-star-inserted']"
```

**Edit 2: Asker had additional question about how to search within what they found with the XPath above.**

To find more elements within these elements here, looking at [the documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement), each Selenium `WebElement` provides its own `find_element` method. You can then use those to further search within those elements we just found (be sure to use `.//` here in your XPaths, as you only want to traverse that specific element's content - other find_elements don't have this caveat).

Once you have identified the elements containing the symbols and prices, you can use simply reference the `text` attribute on those elements. Let's look at a simpler example:

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b" id="1">B</div>
  <div class="c" id="2">2</div>
  <div class="d" id="3">22</div>
</div>
```

Suppose we have already found the root `div` here and stored it in a variable named `element`. Then:

```py
symbol = element.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='b']").text
integral = element.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='c']").text
fractional = element.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='d']").text
```

Generally, if you can search by something other than XPath, though, it's easier for everyone involved. Here is a more typical way you could accomplish this with class names:

```py
symbol = element.find_element_by_class_name("b").text
integral = element.find_element_by_class_name("c").text
fractional = element.find_element_by_class_name("d").text
```

**Edit 3: Note from author**

After the precious help of @firstbass I went in deep to get symbol and different prices for sell/buy as follows:

```
for element in results:
    symbol = element.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='symbol']").text
    print(str(symbol))
    sell = element.find_element_by_xpath(".//et-buy-sell-buttons//et-buy-sell-button//div[@automation-id='buy-sell-button-container-sell']")
    sell_integral = sell.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='price']").text
    sell_fractional = sell.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='after-decimal']").text
    print(str(sell_integral)+':'+str(sell_fractional))
    buy = element.find_element_by_xpath(".//et-buy-sell-buttons//et-buy-sell-button//div[@automation-id='buy-sell-button-container-buy']")
    buy_integral = buy.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='price']").text
    buy_fractional = buy.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='after-decimal']").text
    print(str(buy_integral)+':'+str(buy_fractional))
```

Comment: Thank you @firstbass, I removed the img, not important in this matter. Now it's well formed. The problem about the search of relevant elements remains.

Comment: Thanks, I took another look and believe I found the issue.  I have updated the answer accordingly. Let me know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Great @firstbass! Now it finds correctly 2 instances. Do you have an idea how to extract symbol and prices? Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: I have expanded the answer to help you figure out how to accomplish it, along with some considerations when writing your solution.